# NextJS Go documentation on Vercel

Tags: go, vercel

I read this below and I'm super confused (see pic, url: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/supported-languages). Does this mean I can put both go code and JS code in the same project or do I need 2 separate projects?

I'm trying to setup a Go token server from the Agora documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/token_server (so I was reading about Vercel on how to set up Go.)

When deployed on Vercel, it couldn't find an "exported function", but the code is clearly there, as I followed this documentation and copied that Go code: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/token_server

```
00:54:14.739    Error: Could not find an exported function in "api/server.go"
00:54:14.739    Learn more: https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/go
00:54:14.739    
00:54:14.739    at Object.build (/vercel/b00c4c1ab2469a3f/.build-utils/.builder/node_modules/@vercel/go/dist/index.js:17803:21)
00:54:14.740    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
00:54:14.740    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
00:54:14.740    at buildStep (/var/task/webpack:/@vercel/api/scripts/build-container/src/utils/purpose-build.ts:168:1)
```

Files in my `api` folder:
`go.sum`
`go.mod`
`server.go`

```
//go.mod 
module sampleServer

go 1.17

require github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/go/src v0.0.0-20210806171822-0630dba41e89
```

[image: nextJS vercel]

Comment: Are you locating your Go API on `/pages/api` or your project's root `/api`? Both of them are different.

Comment: `/api/` is where my go code is located. I also have javascript code in `/pages/api`

Comment: I think you have to have an exported function exactly titled `Handler(w http.ResponseWrite, r *http.Request)`. Do you have that function? [Here's the docs](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/go).